# fabricjs groups, not catching the events by mouse

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to catch users click on an Image inside a group. The hierachy is the following

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var group = new fabric.Group();
var myImage;
new fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg){
    myImage = oImg
    group.add(myImage);
    canvas.add(group);
    group.selectable = false;
    canvas.renderAll();
});


myImage.on('mouse:down', function (e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

but it won't work. If change my code to

```
canvas.on('mouse:down' function (e){

    console.log(e);
});
```

it works, but I want to be able to limit clicks on just the image. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the `canvas` needs to add `myImage` as `canvas.add(myImage);`. Thus, the following code will work successfully.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var group = new fabric.Group();
var myImage;
new fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg){
    myImage = oImg
    canvas.add(myImage);
    group.addWithUpdate(myImage);
    canvas.add(group);
    group.selectable = false;
    myImage.on('mouse:down', function (e){
        console.log(e);
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the event for Fabric.Object is 'event:mousedown' or just 'mousedown' (no colon)

See [fabric object docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html)